# How do I use multiple selectors in the same HTML file?

Tags: html, css

One of our homework assignments for the week is putting various selectors into the same file. The textbook we we're given was no help at all and I can't figure out what's going wrong here. The first and fourth  work but the two in the middle don't. I screwed something up as it was working when we did it in class, I just don't know what.

CSS file (everything in here is random just to have it filled in. It wasn't important for the assignment)

```
div.one > p{
    background-color: rgb(154, 212, 212);
    border: 2em;
    border-style: dashed;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
div.two + p{
    background-color: rgb(18, 111, 114);
    border: 10px;
    border-style: dotted;
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: larger;
}
div.three ~ p{
    background-color: hsl(59%, 80%, 22%);
    font-size: 15px;
    border: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
}
div.four{
    border-style: groove;
    border-color: chartreuse;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    background-color: rgb(188, 164, 211);
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML file

```
    <body>
        <div class="one">
            <h4>Section One</h4>
            <p>Paragraph one</p>
            <p>Paragraph two</p>
            <p>Paragraph 3</p>
            <p>Paragraph Four</p>
            <p>Paragraph number 5</p>
            <p>Paragraph 6</p>
        </div>

        <div class="two">
            <div>
            <h4>Section 2</h4>
            <p>Paragraph one</p>
            <p>Paragraph two</p>
            <p>Paragraph 3</p>
            <p>Paragraph Four</p>
            <p>Paragraph number 5</p>
            <p>Paragraph 6</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="three">
            <div>
            <h4>Section 3</h4>
            <p>Paragraph one</p>
            <p>Paragraph two</p>
            <p>Paragraph 3</p>
            <p>Paragraph Four</p>
            <p>Paragraph number 5</p>
            <p>Paragraph 6</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="four">
            <h4>Section 4</h4>
            <p>Paragraph one</p>
            <p>Paragraph two</p>
            <p>Paragraph 3</p>
            <p>Paragraph Four</p>
            <p>Paragraph number 5</p>
            <p>Paragraph 6</p>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: They don't work because they aren't immediate child. Try `.two h1+p`

Comment: Thank you! I thought I had done something much worse than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Everything is right! You understood wrongly!

##### The table:

| Selector | Example | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `element` | `p` | Selects all `<p>` elements |
| `element.class` | `p.intro` | Selects all `<p>` elements with `class="intro"` |
| `element,element` | `div, p` | Selects all `<div>` elements and all `<p>` elements |
| `element element` | `div p` | Selects all `<p>` elements inside `<div>` elements |
| `element>element` | `div > p` | Selects all `<p>` elements where the parent is a `<div>` element |
| `element+element` | `div + p` | Selects the first `<p>` element that is placed immediately after `<div>` elements |
| `element1~element2` | `p ~ ul` | Selects every `<ul>` element that is preceded by a `<p>` element |

###### [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

##### According to the table you can use

- `div.one` ,to Selects **all** `div` elements with `class="one"`
- `div.one,p` ,to Selects **all** `div` elements with `class="one"` *and* **all** `p` elements
- `div.one p` ,to Selects **all** `p` elements ,inside `div` elements with `class="one"`
- `div.one>p` ,to Selects **all** `p` elements where parent is `div` elements with `class="one"`
- `div.one + p` ,to Selects  `p` elements that is placed immediately after `div` elements with `class="one"`
- `div.one ~ p` ,to Selects **all** `p` elements that is placed after `div` elements with `class="one"`

> the last two points here make the second and third *not working*

```css
div.one>p/*Edit here and test*/ 
{
  background-color: rgb(154, 212, 212);
  border: 2em;
  border-style: dashed;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
  <h4>Section One</h4>
  <p>Paragraph one</p>
  <p>Paragraph two</p>
  <p>Paragraph 3</p>
  <p>Paragraph Four</p>
  <p>Paragraph number 5</p>
  <p>Paragraph 6</p>
</div>
```

Note: i have *removed* all other `div` for easy use!,just edit the one code in `css`

> bookmark this for future!